# sorting an array is raising the following error System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have defined the folloing method to sort an array:

```
public int[] BubbleSort(int[] ints)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.Length; i++)
    {
        if (ints[i] > ints[i + 1])
        {
            int tempValue = ints[i];
            ints[i] = ints[i + 1];
            ints[i + 1] = tempValue;         
        }
    }
    return ints;               
}
```

However, my implementation above is throwing System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Index was outside the bounds of the array. What might be the problem?

Comment: You you implementing this for educational purposes or did you need to sort a list of int's and this was your solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `.Length - 1` instead. Also, with [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubblesort), you need to iterate over the array until no more elements should be swapped (this is what makes bubble sort so inefficient):

```
public int[] BubbleSort(int[] ints)
{            
    bool swapped = true;
    while (swapped) 
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < ints.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (ints[i] > ints[i + 1])
            {
                swapped = true;
                int tempValue = ints[i];
                ints[i] = ints[i + 1];
                ints[i + 1] = tempValue;
            }     
        }
    }

    return ints;               
}
```

Comment: although it worked fine,, but i am not sure how i will access the last element in the array while i am having for (int i = 0; i < ints.Length - 1; i++) 
 !!!!!

Comment: on the `i`th element, the `i+1`th element is accessed and swapped if necessary. Take a piece of paper and write out the values of the array for each iteration, it'll be a big help.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ints.Length; i++)
{
  if (ints[i] > ints[i + 1])
```

When `i == ints.Length - 1`, `ints[i + 1]` is an illegal access beyond the end of the array. Your loop logic has an off-by-one error.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < ints.Length-1; i++)

Comment: thanks i modify my code ,, but seems the sorting is not working right.. although logically it should work??

Comment: Logically no it wont, you need to keep looping over the list (or reset back to i = 0, but then I don't think it's a bubble sort anymore) till you go through the list once without swapping. See Andrews answer. To see whats wrong use a pencle and paper and sort the list `3, 2, 1` by hand. After the first swap you get `2, 3, 1` then it moves on and does the next swap `2, 1, 3` and it is done. But it never re-checked that index 0 and index 1 are in order.